# post file using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

this is my code this included jquery php and html code i want to upload file using ajax.
in this code i am unbale to upload a file.
this working perfectly for all other text data but it is not uploading files .file may be pdf doc etc

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
//var password = $("#password").val();
var contact = $("#contact").val();
var applying_for = $("#applying_for").val();

var degree = $("#degree").val();
var experience = $("#experience").val();
var user_cv = $("#user_cv").val();
//var password = $("#password").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email  + '&contact='+ contact+ '&degree='+ degree+ '&applying_for='+ applying_for+ '&user_cv='+ user_cv+ '&experience='+ experience;
if(name==''||email==''||applying_for==''||contact==''||experience=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

```html
  <?php
$error="could not connected";
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","brainmob_web_db") or die($error); // Establishing Connection with Server..
//echo 'connected';
//$db = mysql_select_db("mydba", $connection); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
@$file_name=$_FILES['user_cv']['name'];
$extension=strtolower(substr($file_name,strpos($file_name,'.')+1));

@$size=$_FILES['user_cv']['size'];
@$type=$_FILES['user_cv']['type'];
@$tmp_name=$_FILES['user_cv']['tmp_name'];
//$max_size=100000;//in bytes
//$error=$_FILES['file']['error'];

if(isset($file_name)){

 if(!empty($file_name)){
  /* to specify type of data
  if(($extension=='jpeg'||$extension=='jpg')&&(type='image/jpeg'&&type='image/jpeg')){


  }*/

  //this for any type of data
  $location='uploads_files/';
  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$file_name)){
   echo 'uploaded';
  }
 }else{
  echo 'please choose a file';
 }
}
$name=$_POST['name1'];
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$experience=$_POST['experience'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
//$file=$_POST['file'];
$subject=$_POST['applying_for'];
$degree=$_POST['degree'];
$ip=get_client_ip();

//$browser = get_browser();
//print_r($browser);
 $browser=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];;
 print_r($_POST);
 print_r($_FILES);

//Insert query
echo $query = "insert into brain_career(career_name, career_email,  career_contact,career_experience,career_highest_degree,career_subject,career_file,career_ip,career_browser_info) values ('$name', '$email','$contact','$experience','$degree','$subject',,'$file','$ip','$browser')";

if($query_run=mysqli_query($connection,$query)){
echo 'succesfully inserted';

 }//echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
//print_r(mysqli_error($connection));
//mysqli_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
<form name="contactus_form" id="contactus_form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Name*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name*'">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Email*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email*'">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="contact" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Contact Number*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Contact number'">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="degree"class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Highest Degree*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Highest Degree'">

              <!--  <select id="degree"class="form-control">
                  <option value="">Highest Degree </option>
                </select>-->
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="applying_for"class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Applying For" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Applying For'">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="experience" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Experince in Year" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Experince in Year'">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                  <input type="file" name="user_cv" id="user_cv" class="inputfile inputfile-6"  />
                  <label for="user_cv" class="file-upload"> <span class="form-control attach" id="user_cv_name">Upload Resume</span>
     <strong class="browse-btn butn">Browse</strong></label>
                </div>

               </div>
              <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn-style sub">SUBMIT</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload file using `ajax()`, you have to use `FormData` as there is nothing like `enctype` in ajax.

Ex:

```
var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];  // here pic is the id of input type image
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        // You can add as many key : value pair here like
        form_data.append('var1', val1);

        $.ajax({
                url         : 'upload.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache       : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                data        : form_data,                         
                type        : 'post',
                success     : function(output){
                    alert(output);              // display response from the PHP script, if any
                }
         });
```

upload.php

```
// To receive file
$_FILES['file'];

// To receive other values
$_REQUEST['var1'];
```

Comment: and what about other text data?

Comment: You can add as many key : value pair here like `form_data.append('var1', val1);`

Comment: and how will i retieve this data in php file

Comment: can i pass complete datastring in form_data.append('var1', val1);

Comment: var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email  + '&contact='+ contact+ '&degree='+ degree+ '&applying_for='+ applying_for+ '&user_cv='+ user_cv+ '&experience='+ experience;
if(name==''||email==''||applying_for==''||contact==''||experience=='')

Comment: No, it accept key : value pair like `form_data.append('var1', val1);` ad as many as you required

Comment: so if i want to send name1 email then i will have to do it like  var name = $("#name").val();   form_data.append('name1', name);

Comment: and can i access it like $name=$_POST['name1'];

Comment: Exactly, please check the answer, its mentioned there

Comment: not working it is reddirecting me and showing my file name inside url

Comment: When you are using `<button type="submit"` than you have to use `preventDefault` to hold the form submit

Comment: i new for jquery will u please tell me how to do it ?